# Skype button conflict with bootstrap modals popup

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, skype

i have added a Skype button within a popup bootstrap 2.3.2.
when i click on call or chat then close the popup, Skype keeps asking to connect every time i open the modal popup.

Answer (score 0):

just call function on close button or make event on closing of Modal and in that event u have to make ur skype setting turn off or something related to skype for making it like logout...